Bonmin executable file
I need the bonmin (https://github.com/coin-or/Bonmin) solver for optimization problems in Python. I am newbee in GNU Autotools. I have installed all the necessary environment and the build via GNU Autotools does not return errors. But I cannot find the bin folder where the .exe itself is located in order to register it in &PATH and use the solver in Python.
What do I need to do?
enter image description here
./configure --prefix=D:/Software/Bonmin/bin did not help.
Used msys2 mingw64 for installation
I tried customize ./configure. Was looking for a binary in the msys2 directory, but there was nothing

Do not show images of text. Show the actual text. And don't crop just a few lines, show all the relevant text. With that said, ./configure is step one. You still need to run make to actually compile the thing.
